# How to Retrive Firebase key value based on spinner selection

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, textview, key, spinner

I have a set of course details stored in the firebase Realtime Database. I have retrieved the course names into a spinner for user selection of a particular course. I wanted to get the key (course code) of that particular course to a TextView (in android java) when user select a course from the spinner from firebase database.

I have used the fetchDataForSpinner() method to retrieve the course name to the spinner. But I got confused on how to retrieve the course code to the TextView based on user selection.

I tried to get the key with get key but only the last course key was retrieved.

Firebase Data

[image]

```
  /*Firebase Data
   Courses
        Faculty of IT
          Year 01 Semester 01
            BMG11073:Entrepreneurship &Growing Business
            IT11013:"IT & Computing Fundamentals"
            IT11023:"Programming Fundamentals"
            IT11033:"Statistics"
            IT11041:"Psychology"
            IT11052:"Leadership and Communication Skills"*/


public void fetchDataForSpinner() {
        spinnerReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Courses");
        spinnerReference.child(faculty).child(semester).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot item : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        spinnerCourseList.add(item.getValue().toString());
//                        String courseCodeFromKey = snapshot.getKey();
//                        editTextForCourseCode.setText(courseCodeFromKey);

                    }
                    adapterCourse.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(AddGradesMain.this, "Course Not Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AddGradesMain.this, "Course not added to the database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t understand your question properly. If you provide the a json of your database that will be helpful for give the answer.

But you can get key of a value like this:

```
public void fetchDataForSpinner() {
        spinnerReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Courses");
        spinnerReference.child(faculty).child(semester).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot item : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        spinnerCourseList.add(item.getValue().toString());
                       String courseCodeFromKey = item.getKey();
//                        editTextForCourseCode.setText(courseCodeFromKey);

                    }
                    adapterCourse.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(AddGradesMain.this, "Course Not Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AddGradesMain.this, "Course not added to the database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "Courses": {
    "Faculty of IT": {
      "Year 01 Semester 01": {
        "BMG11073": "Entrepreneurship &Growing Business",
        "IT11013": "IT & Computing Fundamentals",
        "IT11023": "Programming Fundamentals",
        "IT11033": "Statistics",
        "IT11041": "Psychology",
        "IT11052": "Leadership and Communication Skills"
      }
    },

Comment: RmTomal, Iam fetching the values(courses) to a spinner. But I want to display the key which is the course code( eg;BMG11073) when user clicks on a course (Entrepreneurship..).

Comment: RmTomal Thank you for commenting for my question!.. I retrieved the course code to a list and displayed. item.getKey worked for me!